# Connection failure to Salesforce Marketing Cloud using ADF

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory, salesforce-marketing-cloud

We want to ingest data from SFMC using the in-built connector from Azure Data Factory.

The connector needs two things: `client ID` and `client secret`. The team managing SFMC has given me these values but when I try the, I get an error:

`Authentication failed: Malformed response received from the authentication server that does not include the following required parameters for the next authentication step: "Auth_AccessToken" located at "accessToken" from the server response; "Auth_expires" located at "expiresIn" from the server response.`

The SFMC dev team does not what the problem is. We have also raised Salesforce help ticket but they don't know what the problem is either.

**EDIT-1**

I created a POST request using an example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm) and I am getting the response where I can see `access_token` and `expires_in`. But ADF is looking for `accessToken` and `expiresIn`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the statement in the MS [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce-marketing-cloud#supported-capabilities):

> The Salesforce Marketing Cloud connector supports OAuth 2
>   authentication. It is built on top of the Salesforce Marketing Cloud
>   REST API.

Only client id and client secret need to be set in the ADF connector which is obtained from Marketing Cloud | Installed Packages. Please refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm): You do not need a Marketing Cloud user to call the APIs, but you do need a Marketing Cloud user when creating an API integration in Installed Packages. The Marketing Cloud user must have the Installed Package | Administer permission.

According to your issue,it seems that the generation of access token fails.You need to check the above steps or settings of Admin Permission of Installed Packages for ADF.More details,please refer to:

1.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/your-subdomain-tenant-specific-endpoints.htm

2.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm

Comment: Thanks Jay for your reply. I have followed the steps here to install the package. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/create-integration-enhanced.htm In step 3, what type should we use?